# Recovery GPS information with exif_read_data (php)

Tags: gps, php, geophp

I am struggling to understand the EXIF feedback produced by my camera.
Indeed in the Latitude and Longitude fields I receive a figure in this form:

Latitude: 4294967295/341858021

Longitude: 4294967295/724094634

I would like to convert these two parameters to decimal degrees (cf: +-nn.nnnnnnnn).

I don't know how to go about it and I searched in many places on the web but found nothing.

---

My analysis is not complete because reading the exif is more relevant in this sense:

[0] 42/1 represents the °

[1] 4294967295/341858021 presents the '

[2] 0/1 represents the "

Now if i divide 4294967295/341858021 = 14'

42°14'0" In my opinion something is missing, but what?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of where you're getting this data? What is the approximate Lat and Long?

Comment: Are these from - specifically - the GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude tags?

Comment: Can you post the image so we can download it?  Also, use gdalinfo or EXIF Tools (https://exiftool.org/) and post the output to your posting.

Comment: My problem is solved, I found an example under php geotag which got me out of trouble.

Comment: I'd sure like to know what you found. Can you post details as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To read the GPS coordinates from an Exif (see photo jpg) you must locate the GPSlongitute and GPSLatitude beacons. These two fields are ordered in the form of a table:

[0] degrees nn/nn (Lat_degrees)

[1] minutes nnnnnnnn/nnnnnnnn (Lat_minutes)

[2] secondes nnn/nnn  (Lat_seconds)

We also need two other fields:

GPSLatitudeRef GPSLongitudeRef which indicates the 180° to have the + or - (GPSLatitudeRef).

Now the algorithm (Ref php):

Lat = (float) Lat_degrees+(((Lat_minutes*60)+(Lat_seconds))/3600)

GPSLatitudeRef  == 's' ? Lat *= -1 : '' (n, s, w, e)

I hope you understand! (English is not my native language!)